# fb share set the message and image

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

follow official document https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

`share` can set quote or hashtag
`share_open_graph` can change image and title...etc
`feed` all parameters about picture are deprecated

I also try to set **quote** in `share_open_graph`, but not work

my requirement is set **message** and **image**, how can I do it?

Comment: you do know that prefilling the message is not allowed anyway, right? about the image: just use the og:image tag in the source of the shared page.

Comment: @luschn I have used the **og:image** on `share_open_graph`, is it possible to use in `share`?

Comment: just use share instead of share_open_graph, and use og:image in the source.